# How to set the volume of mp3 file in decibel type?

Tags: javascript, volume, decibel

I play a noise and a sound at the same time. I need to increase or decrease the noise in decibels. I have to calculate the SNR value. In a web project, can I output sound in the right decibel when the user's computer is turned all the way up? Please help me set the sound in decibels of the code snippet below.

```js
var a1 = new Audio(`https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3`);
a1.volume= 0.2;
a1.play();
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. How can JS know what is the user speaker wattage?

Comment: you don't control anywhere nearly enough of the user's volume settings for decibels to make any kind of sense. Even if your code set's the _browser_ to increase by 1dB, the master volume might make that only 0.1dB, and if they have an audio interface, that might be a second scaling factor, and if their speakers have separate volume controls, that's a third, etc. etc.

Comment: If you control the entire signal chain from JS engine to speaker output, then you can take measurements yourself and then map decibels to percentages. This is the only way to achieve your goal.